# Display svg element horizontal instead of vertical

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I created a poc of the given link http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502, but i wish to display it horizontal instead of vertical.

I was wondering if that can be done using rotate method, so i tried this:-
d3.select("body").selectAll("svg.box").attr("transform", "rotate(90)");

The mark up given below changes are only the attribute is added but the svg element is still vertical.
Earlier:
The box element
Later:
The box  element

Where am i going wrong?

[image: Vertical svg element]

Comment: See [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/asizer/11198007).

Comment: Why are you rotating by 18 degrees, instead of 90?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out inserted it wrong while typing